# Backbone Validation individual messages placeholders

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using [Backbone Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) and custom messages. I'd like to use a placeholder with the value being validated. Pretty much like the way it's done extending the default messages:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Validation.messages, {
 required: 'This field is required',
 min: '{0} should be at least {1} characters'
});
```

But for individual messages when declaring the validation:

```
validation: {
 field: {
  min: 5,
  msg: '{0} should be at least {1} characters'
 }
}
```

That doesn't work.
I also tried with `'... least ' + this.field.min + ' characters'`, but `this` is undefined.

Anyone knows a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the minLength and maxLength of your input:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Validation.messages, {
     required: 'This field is required',
     minLength: 10,
     min: '{0} should be at least {1} characters'
});
```

According to the documentation:

> The message can contain placeholders for arguments that will be
>   replaced:
>
> - {0} will be replaced with the formatted name of the attribute being    validated
> - {1} will be replaced with the allowed value configured in    the validation (or the first one in a range validator)
> - {2} will be replaced with the second value in a range validator

Comment: When I declare `validation:` I'd like to use the value validated (for example minLenght, or min) in my `msg:` field. And I want to declare in a field by field basis, so I can't extend Validation.messages. Hope that makes it more clear.